# Merging the second column of multple CSV files in git BASH

Tags: bash, csv, command-line, merge, multiple-columns

I am trying to merge all the second columns of mutlple CSV files in a folder into a single CSV file (columnwise). I am failing. When I try to merge cutting the first column it works (by placing -f1) but when i try with the second column (-f2) its just makes a mess. Cant figure out why. Here my code

```
    for i in $FILES; 
do 
paste -d, final_table.csv <(cut -d',' -f 2 --complement "$i") > final_table_intermediate.csv; mv final_table_intermediate.csv final_table.csv ; 

done
```

Thanks in advance
Emiliano

[image: CSV file header]

Comment: Mess in what sense? Why are you using `--complement` if you want to indeed get the second column (rather than everything **except** the second column)?

Comment: If you're working with CSV files, I highly recommend csvkit -- it's a set of CLI tools that'll make scripting a whole lot easier.

Comment: Thank you very much guys! chw21 I will try your code. If i dont use complement, it will merge both column 1 and column 2 and use it as a column in the merged file :(

Comment: Your CSV file doesn't always have a second column. I think this is your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd have a look at the **csvkit**, suggested by @hayden-schiff

If you don't want to go down that road, here's what I came up with.
Though there are a few caveats:

**Update:** Your edit shows that your input files do not always have two columns, and I haven't found a way to make `cut` return an empty string (but with newline) to make the old version work.

So now I'm going through the CSVs line by line, grabbing the value (or an empty string) into a temporary file for each input file, then pasting them all together at the end:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
FILES="infile_??.csv"
FINAL="final_table.csv"
COLUMN="3"

# Delete ${FINAL} if it exists.
[[ -f "${FINAL}" ]] && rm ${FINAL}

TMPFILES=""

for f in ${FILES}; do

    while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        val=$(cut -f ${COLUMN} -d, -s <<< $line)
        [[ -n "${val}" ]] && echo "${val}" || echo "   "
    done < "${f}" > "${f}.${COLUMN}.csv"
    TMPFILES="${TMPFILES} ${f}.${COLUMN}.csv"

done

paste -d, ${TMPFILES} > ${FINAL}
rm ${TMPFILES}
```

Below is my original version which assumes that all files do indeed have at least as many columns as you want to read:

1. Not happy with my solution because you're opening the same file over and over for reading and writing at the same time. I'm curious to know of a method to pass the output of an unknown number of processes as different input streams into a single final process.
2. In your description you want the second column, but you use the `--complement` option which returns *everything except the second column*. This trows me off a bit. I'm ignoring this and go by your description.

So here it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
FILES="infile_??.csv"
FINAL="final_table.csv"
COLUMN="2"

# Delete ${FINAL} if it exists.
[[ -f "${FINAL}" ]] && rm ${FINAL}

for f in $FILES; do
    if [[ -f ${FINAL} ]]; then
        # ${FINAL} already exists from an earlier iteration

        # If you have "moreutils" installed, you can use sponge:
        # cut -d',' -f 2 ${f} | paste -d',' ${FINAL} - | sponge ${FINAL}
        # otherwise you can use "echo" in the way below:
        echo "$(cut -d',' -f ${COLUMN} ${f} | paste -d',' ${FINAL} -)" > ${FINAL}
    else
        # ${FINAL} does not yet exist, we have to create it.
        cut -d',' -f ${COLUMN} ${f} > ${FINAL}
    fi
done
```

Update: My understanding is that it should take the second column of each input file, and write them column after column into the output file, like this:

My input files:

`infile_01.txt`:

```
111, 112, 113
121, 122, 123
131, 132, 133
141, 142, 143
```

`infile_02.txt`:

```
211, 212, 213
221, 222, 223
231, 232, 233
241, 242, 243
```

(So each number is 100 * (file no) + 10 * (row no) + (column no).)

My code, on my computer, produces this output:

```
 112, 212
 122, 222
 132, 232
 142, 242
```

If this is what you get but not what you want, tell me how the output file should look with these input files. If this is not what you get, please run it on your system with my files and tell me what you get.

Comment: Apparently I cant make it work :( I think is merging all the first cells of all the CSV files in the first row and all the second cells in the second row and so on... any clue?

Comment: I have updated my answer with the input files that I used and the output that I got. Please compare this to what you want and/or get.

Comment: Ah this is so frustrating! You code works perfectly if I choose column 1, but if choose column 2 it makes "the mess" again. BTW my files are only 2 columns, I attached the header in the post update, maybe some issue with column 2 structure? cheers

Comment: I've updated my answer. Have a go with the new version.

Comment: Brilliant my friend! I think it worked out, it was running for 4 hours (hundreds of files and with hundreds of row each) but it worked! Bless you! Thanks